# Azure Container Registry CI/CD with Github Actions not working

Tags: azure, github-actions, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to implement a CI/CD workflow in an Azure function with github actions.

The problem I'm having is that even tough, github actions indicates the workflow completed successfully, and even the Azure Deployment Slots indicate an image was pulled, the actual behaviour of the function is not changing.

The logs I added are not showing up.

The github action executed successfully:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F78iG.png)

The Azure workflow says the new image was pulled:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXnlB.png)

But the log stream shows the same old logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Q8D.png)

Even tough my updated code has a new text in the log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Aug.png)

I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone help me?

The problem I'm having is that even tough, github actions indicates the workflow completed successfully, and even the Azure Deployment Slots indicate an image was pulled, the actual behaviour of the function is not changing.

I expected the behaviour of the app to change after making the updates.

Comment: One possible reason for this could be that the function app is not being restarted after the new image is pulled. You can try adding a step in your GitHub Actions workflow to restart the function app after the new image is deployed. Another reason could be that the logs are not being redirected to the correct location. You can try checking the function app's configuration settings to ensure that the logs are being redirected to the correct location.

Comment: References:

-   [Deploy your application to Azure using GitHub Actions workflows created by Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/azure-deployment-using-github-actions?view=vs-2022#deploy-multiple-projects-to-azure-container-apps-using-github-actions)
-   [Continuous deployment with custom containers in Azure App Service (container-linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ci-cd-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#how-cicd-works-with-github-actions)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

The github action step that pushes to the ACR, succedded because I was using valid credentials (ClientID and ClientSecret), some doc I read gave me the impression this were the ones meant to be used. But the correct credentiales were meant to be found on Azure Container Registry > Settings > Access Keys.

Upon changing the credentials, the CI began working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).